# Create C# Algorithm used to calculate NextRunDate for Job Schedules as SQL Agent

Tags: sql, schedule, agent

**Hello,
**I am currently creating a Job Schedule System in C#(Exact the same behaviour as SQL Agent) but I can't create a C# Algorithm that calculate NextRunDate based on Frequency Type such as Daily, Weekly and So on, that produce the same behaviour as SQL Agent; note i used the same table design as sql agent such as Frequency Inteval, Frequency Type and so on.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: "but I can't", what is the difficulty you are running in to?

Comment: also, instead of building your own solution for job scheduling, take a look at Quartz.NET: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/